# android unfortunately stopped after resuming activity for a long time

Tags: android, onresume, android-bundle, android-savedstate

I am creating a simple application. while using my application, when i click home and go to another app and work for some time like 10 to 15 minutes.

When i get back to my app, its will show "unfortunately app stopped" message. And then app closes suddenly.

Exception Throws like this :

```
make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:601)
FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:98)
FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
at ndroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
```

Comment: format your question properly, add non modified stacktrace (aka logcat) or do not expect much attention

Comment: The exception already tells you what to do - to better test this you can activate "do not keep activities" in the developer settings

Comment: How are you constructing and injecting Fragment to the activity? This occurs when you have a custom Fragment constructor with some input parameters... System tries to restore fragment by creating a new one, but it uses empty contructor, and if you have a custom constructor you basically override the default one...